# My driver is `igc` for the ethernet interface. How to get timestamp in ebpf-XDP program?

Tags: timestamp, driver, ebpf, xdp-pdf

The fact is i am a beginner in such programming. How can I get timestamp in the xdp program. A detail step by step instruction would be helpful for me. Right now, even I linked the the header library in the makefile with -l flag but it is not working. [Echoing the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD2SE.png)

Receive nic rx timestamp for every rx packet.

Answer (score 0):

In kernel [v6.3](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3d76a4d3d4e591af3e789698affaad88a5a8e8ab) the [`bpf_xdp_metadata_rx_timestamp`](https://ebpf-docs.dylanreimerink.nl/linux/kfuncs/bpf_xdp_metadata_rx_timestamp/) kfunc was added which adds exactly this functionality.

In kernek [v6.5](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/d677266755c6e55c43b6755673a1eeae3d452e87) support for the igc driver was added.

According to example code found in the kernel selftests this should work (disclaimer: have not personally tested this):

```c
#include <vmlinux.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

extern int bpf_xdp_metadata_rx_timestamp(const struct xdp_md *ctx,
                     __u64 *timestamp) __ksym;

SEC("xdp")
int rx(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    __u64 rx_timestamp;
    int err;

    err = bpf_xdp_metadata_rx_timestamp(ctx, &rx_timestamp);
    if (err)
        return XDP_ABORTED;
    
    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

Note that before the addition of this kfunc this info is also [available](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f64c4acea51fbe2c08c0b0f48b7f5d1657d7a5e4), but only in program that use __sk_buff contexts, so not XDP.

Comment: timestamp_prog_kern.c:29:11: error: implicit declaration of function 'bpf_xdp_metadata_rx_timestamp' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    ret = bpf_xdp_metadata_rx_timestamp(ctx, &timestamp_hw);
          ^
1 error generated.

I have generated and added #include <vmlinux.h>

Comment: The `extern` declaration on line 3 is important. It must be placed in the file before you use it.

Comment: It does not complain now about error, but i could not attach the program:
```
clang -O2 -g -Wall -target bpf -c timestamp_prog_kern.c -o timestamp_prog_kern.o
sudo ip link set enp0s31f6 xdpgeneric obj timestamp_prog_kern.o sec xdp 
libbpf: failed to find valid kernel BTF
libbpf: Error loading vmlinux BTF: -3
libbpf: failed to load object 'timestamp_prog_kern.o'
```

Comment: It seems that your distro/kernel doesn't ship with embedded BTF info normally found at /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux. So you might have to update your OS to a version/distro that does. Try to find or generate BTF info for your currently installed on. You can find precreated BTF blobs for common distros here https://github.com/aquasecurity/btfhub-archive. Or use pahole to generate a custom one. Once you have you should be able to place it at one of these locations to get picked up https://github.com/libbpf/libbpf/blob/445486dcbf9ddd8b3ca799a98ace58d23cee31a1/src/btf.c#L4946